# how to use external css for body tag in jsp

Tags: html, css, jsp, background-image, stylesheet

As of now i am using a css code in the same jsp file to set a background image to my jsp page and i do that by mapping the css code to body tag. It works. It is like:

```
<html>
<style>
body
{
    background:url(deploy/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
<body id="body">
<h1>hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Above jsp is present in web-inf folder and i need to place the css externally in web-inf/deploy/css folder and use the external css throughout all my other jsps.

How do i create an external css in web-inf/deploy/css folder and how do i refer it for body tag in all other jsps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <jsp:include  flush="true" page="deploy/css_folder/body.css.jsp"/>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <h1>hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in body.css.jsp (in deploy/css_folder):

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<style>
body
{
    background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a file

```
myCSS.css
```

Where you put your css code. Put this file in the css folder.
Then in your pages you have to add this:

```
<link href="css/myCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```